# rotate image by 360 degrees using ontouch

Tags: android, image-rotation

I want to rotate an image by 360 degrees using onTouch. With the code i had used the maximum rotation i am getting is 120 degrees. The code i had used is

this is the code in onTouch event

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    newRot = rotation(event);
    float r = newRot - d;
    matrix.postRotate(r, view.getMeasuredWidth()/ 2, view.getMeasuredHeight()/ 2);
```

and the rotation method is

```
private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
    double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
    double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
    double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);

    Log.v("", "=================xxxxxxxxxxxvvvxx==============" + Math.toDegrees(radians));
    return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
}
```

with this code i am getting only 120 degrees rotation on both clockwisw and anti-clockwise. Please suggest me, Did i need to change anything in my code or any working code.

Comment: Rotate three times with 120 and you will get a rotation of 360.

Answer (score 0):

This method might help you it works for me.

```
public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap b, int degrees) {
    if (degrees != 0 && b != null) {
        Matrix m = new Matrix();

        m.setRotate(degrees, (float) b.getWidth() / 2,
                (float) b.getHeight() / 2);
        try {
            Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(),
                    b.getHeight(), m, true);
            if (b != b2) {
                b.recycle();
                b = b2;
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```